# How do i output the city/distance of the layover city the user has provided?

Tags: java, arraylist, graph, hashmap, vertex

So i have a program that represents airline flights. Given the layover city that the user has provided, i need to show all the nodes the selected city is connected to along with the total distances. I am able to output everything correctly, i just need help with the 'showConnections' method. For example Chicago -> New york -> Orlando is 790+1080 = 1870 would be the Total distance.    [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYXV1.png) is how the final output should look like. and [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma5PS.png) is how my code is looking like so far. It looks like its going through the whole loop of my chart and displaying cities when i need only the ones that are connected to New York .

HWDriverPrep.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class HWDriverPrep {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HWGraph g = createGraph();
        printGraph( g );
        Set<String> keys = g.getKeys();
        String startCity = "Chicago";
        String layOver = getLayOverCity( keys, startCity);
        Vertex v = g.getThisVertex( startCity, layOver);
        System.out.printf("\n The connections from Start:%s with layover N:%s are (%s):", startCity, v.label, v.weight);

        showConnections( g, v );
    }
    private static void printGraph(HWGraph g) {
        g.graphMap.forEach(
                (key,value) -> show(key,value));
    }
    private static void show(String key, ArrayList<Vertex> value) {
        System.out.println("Showing connections for key: " + key + "--------");
        for(Vertex v : value){
            System.out.println("City: " + v.label + " Distance: " + v.weight);
        }
    }
    private static String getLayOverCity(Set<String> keys, String startCity) {

        String startNode="";
        //   Arrays.sort(n);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String oStr = "";
        String cm = "";
        for(String item: keys)
        {
            oStr += cm + item;
            cm = ", ";
        }

        System.out.printf("Select a layover City(%s)",oStr);

        String retItem = s.nextLine();
        return retItem;
    }

    private static void showConnections(HWGraph g, Vertex layOverVertex) {
        g.graphMap.forEach(
                (key, value) -> connect(key, value));
    }
        private static void connect(String key, ArrayList<Vertex> value) {

            for(Vertex v : value){
                System.out.println("City: " + v.label + " Distance: " + v.weight);
            }
    }


    private static HWGraph createGraph() {
        HWGraph g = new HWGraph();
        g.addVertex("Chicago");
        g.addVertex("Dallas");
        g.addVertex("Atlanta");
        g.addVertex("New York");
        g.addVertex("Houston");
        g.addVertex("Orlando");

        // --- now add connections
        g.addEdge("Chicago",new Vertex("Dallas",968));
        g.addEdge("Chicago",new Vertex("Atlanta",718));
        g.addEdge("Chicago",new Vertex("New York",790));

        g.addEdge("Dallas",new Vertex("Houston",239));
        g.addEdge("Dallas", new Vertex("Orlando",1120));

        g.addEdge("Houston", new Vertex("Orlando",967));

        g.addEdge("Atlanta", new Vertex("Dallas",781));
        g.addEdge("Atlanta", new Vertex("New York",870));
        g.addEdge("Atlanta", new Vertex("Orlando",438));

        g.addEdge("New York", new Vertex("Houston",1647));
        g.addEdge("New York", new Vertex("Orlando",1080));

        return g;
    }
}
```

Vertex.java

```
public class Vertex {
    String label;
    int weight;
    public Vertex(String label, int weight) {
        this.label = label;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

HWGraph.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class HWGraph {
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Vertex>> graphMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void addVertex( String label ){
        ArrayList<Vertex> items = new ArrayList<>();
        graphMap.put( label, items);
    }
    public void removeVertex( String label ){

    }
    public void addEdge( String label1, Vertex v){
        graphMap.get(label1).add(v);
//        graphMap.get(label2).add(label1);
    }
    ArrayList<Vertex> getConnections( String label){
        return graphMap.get(label);
    }
    Set<String> getKeys( ){
        Set<String> keys = graphMap.keySet();
        return keys;
    }
    Vertex getThisVertex( String startCity, String destCity){
        ArrayList<Vertex> destCities = this.getConnections( startCity);
        for( Vertex v : destCities){
            if ( v.label.equalsIgnoreCase(destCity)){
                return v;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the methods `printGraph` and `showConnections`:

```java
private static void printGraph(HWGraph g) {
  g.graphMap.forEach(
      (key, value) -> show(key, value));
}

private static void showConnections(HWGraph g, Vertex layOverVertex) {
  g.graphMap.forEach(
      (key, value) -> connect(key, value));
}
```

You see that they effectively do the same thing, they call a method for each entry in the global list of available connections.
The parameter `layOverVertex` in `showConnections` is completely unused, but  you should filter the `HWGraph g` by the layover.

Then compare your methods `show` and `connect`, `show` is used for the global list of connections, while `connect` should show the connections starting in the layover city and also add the distance to get there to all distances:

```java
private static void show(String key, ArrayList<Vertex> value) {
  System.out.println("Showing connections for key: " + key + "--------");
  for(Vertex v : value){
    System.out.println("City: " + v.label + " Distance: " + v.weight);
  }
}

private static void connect(String key, ArrayList<Vertex> value) {
  for (Vertex v : value) {
    System.out.println("City: " + v.label + " Distance: " + v.weight);
  }
}
```

You see that the methods are quite similar, just `show` prints an additional header, otherwise they are equal.
Notice that the parameter `key` is only used in the `show` method to print the header, it is completely unused in the `connect` method. Also the `connect` method doesn't know about the distance to add - there is no parameter for that.

So what you are missing is:

- filter the full map of connections by the layover city (hint: `Map.entrySet()` provides you with a set of all entries in the map)
- add the distance from the starting city to the layover city (initial distance) as parameter to the `connect` method, add a third value to the output that displays the sum of the initial distance and the distance to the target
- remove the parameter `key` from the `connect` method if you don't need it there (e.g. for some additional output)

Comment: so should i get rid of connect entirely?

Comment: no, it is just lacking information that you wanted to print out (the total distance per connection). I didn't check the full text output, but maybe you want to add a different header in there? (different to `show`)